# Copy Azure blob to local machine as soon as blob is created

Tags: azure, service, windows-services, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I'm trying to create a Windows service that will detect when a new blob is uploaded to a certain container on Azure and download them onto the local machine immediately. I know I can have a blob trigger running locally but there doesn't seem to be any way to put this into a service. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Instead of downloading on your local machine, will a solution be acceptable where the blob gets downloaded to a publicly accessible server (through HTTP) in your infrastructure?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: What happens when your machine is unavailable (say machine is shut down)?

Comment: Then the process that needs said files isn't running either.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with using the standard WebJobs SDK with a blob trigger, but running as a service instead of a console app.

You can find more information about using the blob trigger with the SDK directly here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Blobs